# java.net.MalFormedURLException: unkown protocol : abfss

Tags: xml, scala, azure, xsd, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to validate an XML file against XSD from ADLS Gen2(Azure Blob file storage system). I am taking reference from below link

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/XML_validation#Scala

This code is working fine for local or dbfs path, But i am getting error when i try to fetch file from the ADLS Gen2 URL.

Error : "java.net.MalFormedURLException: unkown protocol : abfss".

If anyone implemented some solution for this then please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You give it the wrong url, looks like a typo in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks Dima for your quick reply, Could you please share me some sample with https Url. So that I can directly fetch the data from the azure blob storage using account keys

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) help?